# Usando el "sí" para enfatizar

Tags: uso-de-palabras, adverbios

Tengo curiosidad sobre el uso de «sí» en esta frase:

> Aunque, curiosamente, hubo una planta en España que **sí** logró reciclarlo al 100%, hoy no existe en el país la tecnología necesaria para evitar que una parte vaya al vertedero.
>
> <sub>eldiario.es en [*Tetrabrik, el residuo que hoy ya nadie puede reciclar al 100% en España*](https://www.eldiario.es/ballenablanca/365_dias/Tetrabrik-residuo-nadie-reciclar-Espana_0_867213358.html))</sub>

También encontré otros ejemplos:

> A veces no es posible influir directamente sobre esas entidades y es necesario operar sobre otros que **sí** influyen.
>
> Lo que **sí** se necesita es voluntad política.

¿Funciona el «sí» para enfatizar la cláusula que sigue al «que»? Si se omite el «sí», ¿se cambiará tanto el significado?

Finalmente, ¿tiene un término correcto este uso de «sí»?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El uso del adverbio afirmativo *sí* sí (jaja) enfatiza lo que se dice en el verbo que le sigue de algunas formas.  No hay un nombre muy específico, pero en por lo menos una parte de la Nueva Gramática se le llama el **adverbio enfático sí**

> Extracto de la *Nueva Gramática* (40.4e, pp. [2986](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SeVHzqRltiSbtdLg)-[2987](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=buIkzfbzffKjLIgw))
>
> Son [otra estructura] más propiamente contrastivos los grupos verbales a los que se antepone el adverbio enfático *sí*: la expresión *el lugar al que **sí** me gustaría ir* se diferencia de *el lugar al que me gustaría ir* en que en la primera expresión el hablante contrasta a un determinado lugar con otros posibles, supuestamente presentados en el discurso anterior, que se rechazan o se descartan.

No tiene por qué venir después de un *que*, vale en cualquier cláusula, sea independiente o no, pero sí antes del verbo principal de la dicha cláusula.  He aquí algunos ejemplos:

> Yo hablo portugués. *(declaración normal)*
>   Yo sí hablo portugués.  *(alguien expresó su duda)*
>
> Voy a buscar un sitio donde haya cerveza. *(declaración normal, a ver qué encuentro)*
>   Voy a buscar un sitio donde sí haya cerveza. *(ya he pasado por varios sin encontrarla)*

El significado exacto puede variar según el contexto.  Puede ser informativo, contrastivo, refutativo, o exclamativo.